# Resteasy PostProcessInterceptor after ResteasyJacksonProvider

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

We have a Resteasy webservice.

I use Jackson provider for JSON, both outgoing JSON in response and incoming JSON in request.

Is it possible to have a PostProcessInterceptor to be executed after JSON-Jackson serialization?

My PostProcessInterceptor has to change the JSON content for every outgoing response. But when the PostProcessInterceptor is executed if I print the entity `response.getEntity().toString();` I see the toString method of the java.lang.Object, not the JSON String. That's because the Object has not yet been serialized by Jackson.

Is it possible to serialize with Resteasy/Jackson **before** running the PostProcessInterceptor?

I've also tried to use `@Precedence` annotation on my PostProcessInterceptor. But it doesn't work, even using "DECODER" precedence (which is the last one).

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a CDI interceptor instead. You can get the intercepted method parameters from the InvocationContext and change them if necessary.

Comment: I'm looking for an interceptor that process all the outgoing body responses (not the incoming request), is this possible with CDI Interceptor? I'm currently reading the documentation, is this what you are suggesting to me? http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.5.Final/en-US/html/interceptors.html

Comment: If you're interested on the response object before it gets serialized by Resteasy then yes. Change that and the resulting JSON will follow. You can just get the context.proceed() response Object and cast it (yikes!) or catch outgoing exceptions.

If you need to see the final result after all exception mappers have done their jobs and make changes to the actual JSON string then you will can maybe try a MessageBodyWriterInterceptor. Haven't done one myself so it's just an informed guess.

Comment: Right, I said "Is it possible to have a PostProcessInterceptor to be executed after JSON-Jackson serialization?" So I'm interested in the JSON String in the response body, not the object. 
So your suggestion is MessageBodyWriterInterceptor. Seems a good solution, I'll let you know!